# VSCode cannot open clicked file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Normally when you simply click on a file on the left navbar - the VSCode Files Explorer, the file will be showed. 
But i seem to run to some problems when I turned off my computer will the VSCode is not completely terminated.

Now when I click on files in the VSCode Files Explorer and nothing happened, then in order to open the file, I have to drag it to the mainspace. 
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This is my VSCode info:
Version: 1.73.1 (user setup) 
Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b
Date: 2022-11-09T04:27:29.066Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No

Comment: Can you please bring some more information to the question? such as you OS and some related information.

Comment: Close every window restart Your Computer and try again. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: did you try "reload window"?

Comment: that's a pretty old version of VS Code. why doesn't you upgrade to the latest? It's not like you're stuck on an old Windows OS version. also, still waiting on an extension bisect

Comment: Thanks guys, I've just deleted folder %APPDATA%\Code to reset setting and it seems to be fine now.